# Missing reputation change on reputation tab after undelete of an answer converted to community wiki

Tags: support, deleted-answers, community-wiki, reputation-history

**Background**:

One of my questions (on another SE site) was converted to a Community Wiki question (not by me). Additionally my own answer to the question was also converted to a Community Wiki (not by me). And my question was "locked".

Later on my question and my answer was edited (not by me). The edited versions of my (locked) question and my answer deviated so much from what my OP was about, that I could not agree anymore with its newest content. After some attempts to undo those edits of my question and my answer (overruled by moderation), I decided to delete that answer.

A few days after I deleted my own answer, the "lock" of my question was removed. After I noticed that, I was able to perform a "rollback" of my question to a prior (slightly edited) version of it.

The steps detailed above resulted in a (correct) *Reputation summary* like so:

1. Before my answer was converted to a community wiki, it had 3 upvotes (= `+30` rep change).
2. After conversion to community wiki, it gained another 3 upvotes (no more rep changes of course, because it had become a CM answer).
3. When I deleted my answer, it caused a rep change of `-30` (as I predicted before delete, so OK).

**Missing reputation change after undelete**:

Now that, after a few weeks, the rolled back version of my question is still the current version, I performed these steps (today):

1. Undelete my own answer.
2. Rollback my answer to a, to me, acceptable prior version.

I could complete these 2 steps as I wanted to. However I believe something is missing in the reputation changes related to it:

- When I deleted my answer, it resulted in a rep change of `-30`, which was reflected in the weekly/monthly/quarterly reputation changes also.
- The undelete of my answer now seems to have resulted in a `+30` rep change in my "total reputation" (which I believe is correct), but it is not reflected in the weekly/monthly/quarterly reputation changes.

**My question**: Why is that reputation change (`+30`) missing on my reputation tab for today (and the weekly/monthly/quarterly reputation changes)? Is it a bug, or some SE-rule I'm not aware of yet?

**Note**: I'm using 'show removed posts'.

Answer (score 1):

It is missing because actually you didn't *earn* any rep on the day you undeleted your answer. You got the rep lost due to deleting back, and the rep earned by you with this answers again appears on the days you *actually earned* it ([oct 5](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/39516/pierre-vriens?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) and oct 6), as if you didn't delete your answer at all. As you can see, the upvotes you received for the post today are correctly depicted in your rep tab for today. The leagues count the rep by the same principle.

(If you still want to see the rep you lost by deleting and regained by undeleting, check "show removed posts")

---

A little bit of clarification.

If the "show removed posts" is unchecked, when you remove your answer, the upvotes shown at the days oct 5 and 6 are simply removed from the reputation tab; when you undelete, the upvotes for oct 5 and 6 are back.

If "show removed posts" is checked, the upvotes are not removed, but you get "-x rep | removed | {post name}" event for the day you delete. When you undelete you also get the event the day you undelete.

Leagues, again, work the first way. When a post is removed, it's treated as if it never existed, when it's undeleted it's treated as never having been deleted.

Comment: Thanks nicael for this answer. I understand what you wrote about the oct 5 / oct 6 rep changes as related to the 3 upvotes (= the +30 rep). But the "You got the rep lost due to deleting back" isn't clear to me yet. Are you saying something like "now that you undeleted it (today), the -30 rep because of that delete (somewhere after oct 6) has today been removed from my reputation tab again"? At least that is how it appears to be now (looking at my reputation history since oct 6). If you can, can you refine/tune your answer please to clarify this?

Comment: @Pierre sorry for being unclear; tried to clarify.